# Use formData to upload two filetypes in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, react-native, form-data

I would like my uploadFormPage() function to be able to take jpegs and pdf's. Is it possible for me to have 2 file types for the same FormData() const?`

```
export function uploadFormPage(documentId, formId, file, callback) {
  return async dispatch => {
try {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('page', {
    name: `document-${documentId}-${formId}-${Date.now()}.jpg`,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    uri: file,
  });
  const result = await Api.uploadFiles(formData);
  const entity = {
    id: formId,
    resourceKey: result.page,
  };
  const rsp = await Api.uploadFormPage(documentId, entity);
  dispatch({type: LOAD_DOCUMENTS, data: rsp});
  callback(null, rsp);
} catch (e) {
  callback(e, null);
}
};
}
```

Comment: When uploading files, I believe each file should be uploaded with it's own form data configurations. Hence it wouldn't be possible to upload several files using the same form data

Comment: ah thank you, I figured that was the case but I def needed a second opinion.